# Django: how to create group programmatically

Tags: python, django

In Django, how to create groups programmatically?

The point is, I want to create fixture data for my Django project, but I want to do it with Python since I feel more comfortable working on Python.

I want to create a simple group, with just a name, no permission. I create a script like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

testgroup = Group()
testgroup.name = 'testgroup'
testgroup.save()
```

But when I run this script:

```
python testgroup.py
```

I receive the following error:

*django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before acces*

Any help please? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using Django models inside your script, you need to run the code within a Django environment (e.g. it needs the `settings.DATABASES` value in your `settings.py` to talk to your DB), you can turn it into a Django management command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

So just put your code inside the `handle()` method of your command, then e.g. run `manage.py testgroup`